# Mathematica stops showing messages, how to get them back?

Tags: warning-messages, usage-messages

I realized that, for an identical expression, sometimes I get an error message and sometimes I don't. If I then shut down and restart Mathematica, messages are back.

How can I get messages back without restarting Mathematica?

Here is an example:

```
In[1]:= ClearAll["Global`*"]
In[8]:= Solve[Log[x] == Exp[x] - 5, x]

During evaluation of In[8]:= Solve::nsmet: This system cannot be solved 
with the methods available to Solve.

Out[8]= Solve[Log[x] == -5 + e^x, x]
```

Some other times, I just get:

```
In[1]:= ClearAll["Global`*"]
In[8]:= Solve[Log[x] == Exp[x] - 5, x]
Out[8]= Solve[Log[x] == -5 + e^x, x]
```

Comment: Without a reproducible example, we can't say much.

Comment: Can u add some code that demos the issue?

Comment: As Szabolcs said, it's difficult to say unless the behavior is reproducible for everyone and I'm afraid I'm not able to reproduce this, but whenever someone is asking about 'weird' behavior, this is a good place to start [Resetting Mathematica](http://support.wolfram.com/kb/12464). (Could you have inadvertently clicked the `...` button in front of the message and turned it off?)